# Tensorflow L2 loss definition

Tags: math, tensorflow

I was wondering why [tf.nn.l2_loss](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/l2_loss) was set to compute half the L2 norm. Is there any special meaning to divide the L2 norm by 2?

Answer (score 3):

It is just to simplify its derivatives (cancelling the `2` coefficients appearing from derivating the squared elements)